# Sigma-algebra generated by the inverse image.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $$ f:(X,\Sigma_X)\longrightarrow (Y,\Sigma_Y)$$ be a meausurable function.

We defined a $\sigma-$algebra in $Y$, by $\mathcal{M} = \{ B\in \mathcal{P}(Y): f^{-1}(B)\in \Sigma_X \}$.

Now, given that $f$ is measurable, then $f^{-1}(B) \in\Sigma_X$ for all $B\in\Sigma_Y$.

This implies, that $\mathcal{M}\subset\Sigma_Y$?

Or what is the relation between $\mathcal{M}$ and $\Sigma_Y$?

Comment: there can be $B$ in $\mathcal M$ and not in $\Sigma_Y$ such that the preimage is in $\Sigma_X$. The containment is the other way round. $\mathcal M$ is in some sense the ‘largest’ $\sigma$ algebra for which $f$ is also measurable. By way of example you may want to consider $f=0$ a constant function. Then $\mathcal M = \mathcal P(Y)$ which is strictly larger

Comment: Sure, thank you very much.

Comment: you're welcome. (I should have said, "is (probably) strictly larger", since we don't know if $\Sigma_Y= \mathcal P(Y)$ at this level of generality.)